# What is the meaning of several words separated by colons in an XML namespace?

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I am trying to work with some XML (a SOAP -> WSDL service request) in which I have an XML schema with the namespace like:

NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0

```
<xs:schema id="ImageQuery_1.0" 
    targetNamespace="NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0"
    xmlns="NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0"
    xmlns:mstns="NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"> ...remainder of xsd...
```

I keep getting this error from the web service I am requesting:

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0:ImageQuery'.
```

Can someone please help me understand formatting namespaces like this, and perhaps point me to some reading? I have been looking for several hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A construct like xmlns:mstns="NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0" is mapping from a prefix (mstns) to a namespace URI (purported to be NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0).

[RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) defines the syntax or a URI. What you have here is a perfectly valid non-hierarchical URI with a scheme of NWMLS.

Your error message indicates that you just don't have a W3C XML Schema with targetNamespace of the URI. The URI is just a string that uniquely identifies the schema.

It has nothing to do with the syntax or format. In fact, it has a very simple syntax: NWMLS is the scheme, and everything else is just an opaque lump.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like I need to figure out why there is no W3C XML Schema with a targetNamespace of the URI. Any suggestions on how I can go about this, or perhaps another resource for me to read? I read the RFC (the applicable parts at least...thanks for that). Also, since this is not a URL, how am I supposed to specify WHERE the schema is located even if there was a schema with the target namespace of the URI? Thanks for the help, really

Comment: There may be a schema and they may simply not have sent it to you. Note that an http:// URI does _not_ designate the location of the schema.

Comment: In some environments, you'd use an OASIS catalog to map such a URI to an actual location.

Comment: There is a schema file, an .xsd file called NWMLS_EverNet_ImageQuery_1.0.xsd, and it is a local file - I have it on my server. I received this file from the system host - the people running the web service I am requesting. Is it enough to just point to this file locally?

Comment: Well, yes. That's what a catalog does. Since you haven't told us what platform / package you are using to try to parse this thing, I can't help you out with 'how'.

Answer (score 3):

There is no meaning. It's just a string. You get the error because the service doesn't know about the schema corresponding to the namespace.

Comment: Hmm...How is there no meaning, wouldn't that just make it filler? What does that kind of namespace do when there are several words separated by colons? I understand why I got the error. Maybe I wasn't clear on my question, I'm trying to understand what the xmlns="NWMLS:EverNet:ImageQuery:1.0" is doing. Thanks man.

Comment: I'm still looking up the answer to my question, but to expand on what you said John, I think what you meant by a URI being "just a string" was this:
a URI is "little more than a structured string that supports the syntactic, scheme-independent operations of comparison, normalization, resolution, and relativization." What all that means, I'm still trying to discern. Anyway, here's the resource for anyone else who has my same question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html . I will continue posting my exact findings.

Comment: In the context of XML namespaces, a URI with the colons in it has the same "meaning" as a URI with "http://". It's just a name that uniquely designates the schema.

Comment: As far as namespaces are concerned, the internal structure of the URI is irrelevant: it's only purpose is to give human readers a clue about who invented it and why. For any software reading the XML, the only significance of the string is that it's different from other strings denoting other namespaces. (What does "Michael" mean? Well, he was an archangel... But if you're looking for Michael and can't find him, this information isn't going to help you...)